# Visual Studio Tab Groups on Multiple Monitors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, tabs, multiple-monitors

My current setup has one large monitor and one smaller monitor.  I have VS 2010 expanded to fill both monitors, and I have two horizontal Tab Groups set up on the larger and one on the smaller.  Problem is, every time I run the program, VS automatically repositions the dividers so that they're evenly spaced across the combined monitor space, causing the middle panel to be split down the middle.  I then have to move the dividers back where I want them - one right between the screens and one halfway across the larger screen.  Then when I stop the program, it resets them AGAIN, and I have to constantly repeat this process, which is not only really annoying, but also slow and unresponsive when dealing with the very large code-base I'm currently working on.  Is there some way to tell VS to just leave my window positioning alone between running and stopping execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an exact answer to your question but perhaps you'd have better luck just grabbing the tab and dragging it to the other monitor.  It basically acts like a new window that stays open on the other monitor.  Form that tab you can build a tab group?

Again, not sure if this would help, but is how I do it.

as explained by [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/31/multi-monitor-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx)

Comment: ...Well, it was sort of working.  Until VS decided that the Solution Navigator should fill the entire screen when running.  Tip: Don't ever try to move the SN outside of the home window.  Then when trying to switch everything around, VS glitched like crazy and ultimately crashed - trying again.  Sigh.

Comment: Okay, after much dragging of tabs (individually, because apparently you can't drag a whole group), I've got the following setup:  Small monitor has the home window, one tab group, and the Solution Explorer/Properties/Assorted Debug windows.  Large monitor has a floating pane with 2 horizontal tab panels.  Only downside is when closing and reopening solution, the floating panel doesn't maximize on its screen, but this is easily correctable.  It's also a little glitch still switching between running and not running.  And it was way more tedious than it should've been to set that up...